# Array length trouble in Java?

Tags: java, diophantine

so I am in the middle of working on a problem requiring me to:

> Use 3 nested loops to generate every combination of (F^5-E^5-D^5) store all these combinations.  Then use 3 different nested loops to generate every combination of (A^5+B^5+C^5) and store all these values.  Where 0 < A ≤ B ≤ C ≤ D ≤ E ≤ F ≤ N

I have been following this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13317996/generating-values-for-diophantine-equations-in-java?) which is exactly what I am trying to accomplish.

The problem I am having is the way my code is set up, the array that I am storing the values in will be overwritten every time the loop goes around again.

How long does the array need to be to store the values (N^3 maybe)?  And how can I do it without overwriting?

Here is my code so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the value for N:");

    int n = scan.nextInt();
    int countF = n;

    double[] fifth_orderN = new double[n+1];
    double[] F_answer = new double[n+1];
    double[] A_answer = new double[n+1];

    for(int i = 1; i != n+1; i++)
    {
        fifth_orderN[i] = Math.pow(i, 5);
    }

    for(int i = 1; i != n+1 ; i++)
    {
        double F = Math.pow(countF, 5);
        countF--;

        for(int j = 1; j != n+1 ; j++)
        {
            double E = fifth_orderN[j];

            for(int k = 1; k != n+1; k++)
            {
                double D = fifth_orderN[k];
                double ans = (F-(D+E));

                if(ans < 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    F_answer[k] = ans;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i = 1; i != n+1; i++)
    {
        double A = fifth_orderN[i];

        for(int j = 1; j != n+1; j++)
        {
            double B = fifth_orderN[j];

            for(int k = 1; k != n+1; k++)
            {
                double C = fifth_orderN[k];
                double ans = (A + B + C);
                A_answer[k] = ans;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To do it without overwriting: instead of `F_answer[k]`, define another variable that holds "the next index where you're going to put an answer", e.g. `answerIndex`.  Then, to add an answer, `F_answer[answerIndex]=ans; answerIndex++;` or more simply `F_answer[answerIndex++]=ans;`.  There are other details that I'll leave it up to you to work out.

Comment: Ah, perfect!  Thank you!
And am I correct in assuming the length of that array will be (N^3)?

Comment: If the rest of your program is correct, then yes, it looks like N^3 is the right length.  Of course you probably won't fill every element, but N^3 should work as an upper bound.